# decorator field not working in supper class with TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, decorator

In file `base.ts`

```
export const INCLUDED_FIELDS = new Map<string, string[]>();
export function JsonInclude(cls: any, name: string){
   let clsName = cls.constructor.name;
    let list: string[];

    if (INCLUDED_FIELDS.has(clsName)) {
        list = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(clsName);
    } else {
        list = [];
        INCLUDED_FIELDS.set(clsName, list);
    }

    list.push(name);
}

export default class Base{
    @JsonInclude
    public  name: string;

    toJSON(): { [name: string]: any } {
        let json = {};
        let include = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(this.constructor.name);

        cc.log(include);
        Object.getOwnPropertyNames(this).filter(name => include.indexOf(name) > 0).forEach(name => {
            cc.log("adding " + name);
            json[name] = this[name];
        });

        return json;
    }

}
```

And in `staff.ts`

```
export default class Staff extends Base {
   
    @JsonInclude
    public salary: number = 1000;

    @JsonInclude
    public level: number = 1;

    @JsonInclude
    public comment:string = "";
}
```

It seems that the `name` field in the `Base` class won't be added to the `INCLUDED_FIELDS` list?

Comment: `IGNORE_FIELDS` in `JsonInclude` function should be `INCLUDED_FIELDS`, right?

Comment: @hoangdv you are right, sorry for the confusion, have just changed that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"It seems that the `name` field in the `Base` class won't be added to the `INCLUDED_FIELDS` list". In actually, `name` will be added to the map, but it store in other key name. Your map will be look like

```
Map {
  'Base' => [ 'name' ],
  'Staff' => [ 'salary', 'level', 'comment' ],
}
```

For the `Base` class, you apply `JsonInclude` decorator for the `name` field. Now the first parameter of `JsonInclude` - `cls` will be `Base`, this mean `cls.constructor.name` will return `"Base"` and this is the first key name of the map.

The same situation for the `Staff` class, `cls.constructor.name` will return `"Staff"`

Finally, you call `toJSON` on a instance of `Staff` class:

```
const staff = new Staff();
console.log(staff.toJSON());
```

`this` context in line `let include = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(this.constructor.name);` is `Staff` instance (`this.constructor.name` return `"Staff"`), then you just get `'Staff' => [ 'salary', 'level', 'comment' ]` value of the map.

The solution, use only one key name for a "class type". This is a function what return the "root" class name of a class.

```
function getRootClassName(cls: any): string {
  let clsName = cls.constructor.name;

  let parentCls = Object.getPrototypeOf(cls);
  while (parentCls.constructor.name !== "Object") {
    clsName = parentCls.constructor.name;
    parentCls = Object.getPrototypeOf(parentCls);
  } 
  return clsName;
}
```

Example: Object->Base->Staff ===> The function will return "Base" string for "Base" instance or "Staff" instance.

Now, your decorator will be like:

```
export default function JsonInclude(cls: any, name: string) {
  let clsName = getRootClassName(cls);
  let list: string[];

  if (INCLUDED_FIELDS.has(clsName)) {
    list = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(clsName);
  } else {
    list = [];
    INCLUDED_FIELDS.set(clsName, list);
  }

  list.push(name);
}
```

and `toJSON` function will be like:

```
toJSON(): { [name: string]: any } {
    let json: any = {};
    let include = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(getRootClassName(this)) || []; // get key name

    for (const name in this) {
      if (include.indexOf(name) >= 0) { // === 0 for the first item of include
        console.log("adding " + name);
        json[name] = (this as any)[name];
      }
    }

    return json;
  }
```

I use `for...in` instead of `getOwnPropertyNames`, because `getOwnPropertyNames` just returns all properties found directly in a given object (not from parent object)

Final code:

`base.ts`

```
export const INCLUDED_FIELDS = new Map<string, string[]>();

function getRootClassName(cls: any): string {
  let clsName = cls.constructor.name;

  let parentCls = Object.getPrototypeOf(cls);
  while (parentCls.constructor.name !== "Object") {
    clsName = parentCls.constructor.name;
    parentCls = Object.getPrototypeOf(parentCls);
  } 
  return clsName;
}

export default function JsonInclude(cls: any, name: string) {
  let clsName = getRootClassName(cls);
  let list: string[];

  if (INCLUDED_FIELDS.has(clsName)) {
    list = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(clsName);
  } else {
    list = [];
    INCLUDED_FIELDS.set(clsName, list);
  }

  list.push(name);
}

export default class Base {
  @JsonInclude
  public name: string = '';

  toJSON(): { [name: string]: any } {
    let json: any = {};
    let include = INCLUDED_FIELDS.get(getRootClassName(this)) || [];

    for (const name in this) {
      if (include.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
        console.log("adding " + name);
        json[name] = (this as any)[name];
      }
    }

    return json;
  }
}
```

`staff.ts`

```
export default class Staff extends Base {

  @JsonInclude
  public salary: number = 1000;

  @JsonInclude
  public level: number = 1;

  @JsonInclude
  public comment: string = "";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

That is because decorators are not inherited. Decorators are called when a class is defined not instantiated. Class inheritance is more complex than just making copy-paste, if you looked more into it you know you also have `super` call which will allow you to access such inherited class (proving that the base class really isn't just hard-pasted during compilation)

That being said, **when inheriting a class, such class is already declared**. Therefore, the decorator does not trigger - it simply can't.

You can see it nicely in this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ts-decorator-inheritance